# Google Guice + TestNG(v6.14.3) groups throws java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate resource

Tags: java, testng, guice, testng.xml

I have below hierarchy

```
@Guice(modules = ServiceModule.class)
public abstract class BaseTest {
  @Inject
  protected FooBarService _fooBarService;

  //some generic stuff here
  //used TestNG @BeforeSuite etc tags here
}
```

Then I inherit `BaseTest` in `NextBase` as below with some classes Injected

```
public class NextBase extends BaseTest { 
   @Inject
   protected BlaBlaService _blaBlaService;

  //again some generic stuff here
  //used TestNG @Before/After etc tags here
}
```

**and finally I have my Test class which works without TestNG groups as below**

```
public class MyTests extends NextBase {

 @Test
 firstTest(){
  //test implementation 
 }

 @Test
 secondTest(){
  //test implementation 
 }
}
```

**But If I introduce TestNG groups, I got the error to instantiate the object using `@Inject`.** How can I get rid of it?

```
public class MyTests extends NextBase {

  @Test(groups = {"ReadOnly"})
  firstTest(){
   //test implementation   
  }

  @Test(groups = {"ReadOnly"})
  secondTest(){
   //test implementation   
  }
 }
```

I have a `final` BaseClass of all `@Inject` Services, I think that `final class` is causing this issues? how can I overcome this?

```
/**
 * Base class for services that need access to the resource SDKs.
 * This class isolates consumers from having to worry about the lazy-injected SDK resource classes.
 */
public final class SdkService { }
```

**Get error as**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate resource
    at com.abc.test.service.SdkService.getResource(SdkService.java:392)
    at com.abc.test.service.SdkService.getOrgResource(SdkService.java:248)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:529)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:497)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:951)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:831)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:729)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not able to control the test cases using `TestNG Groups`, I decided to put `ReadOnly`, `Provisioning` etc test cases in separate classes and now I logically grouped the test cases.

```
<test name="My Tests" preserve-order="true">

<!-- <groups> // this won't possible for me.
      <run>
        <include name="ReadOnly" />
        <include name="Provisioning" />
      </run>
    </groups>-->
<classes>
    <!-- below is logical grouping of my test cases.. Yeah !! -->
    <class name="com.abc.test.ReadOnlyTests"/>
    <class name="com.abc.test.ProvisioningTests"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```